# How to check if a marker is in a bounding box with Leaflet

Tags: coffeescript, leaflet

In my example I'm trying to check if the marker is within the bounding box.  If it is, the popup text gets set to true.

I keep ending up with "L.latlngBounds" is not a function.
Would somebody be able to point me in the correct direction?

```
checkBounds = (marker) ->
  if L.latlngBounds(inBounds).contains(currentMarker.getLatLng())
    return "True"
  else
    return "False"

map = L.map('mapid').setView([
  51.505
  -0.09
], 13)
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors').addTo map

neCorner = L.marker([47.6349, -122.3206])
swCorner = L.marker([47.6341, -122.3211])
currentMarker = L.marker([47.6345, -122.3208])
inBounds = new L.featureGroup([swCorner, neCorner])

map.fitBounds(inBounds.getBounds(), { padding: [50, 50] } )
currentMarker.addTo(map).bindPopup(checkBounds(currentMarker)).openPopup()
```

**update**
couldn't figure out how to post code in a comment, so I'll do it here

```
checkBounds = (marker) ->
    if L.latLngBounds([swCorner, neCorner]).contains(marker)
    return "True"
  else
    return "False"

map = L.map('mapid').setView([
  51.505
  -0.09
], 13)
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors').addTo map

neCorner = L.latLng([47.6349, -122.3206])
swCorner = L.latLng([47.6341, -122.3211])

currentMarker = L.latLng([47.6355, -122.3208])

map.fitBounds(([swCorner, neCorner]), { padding: [50, 50] } )
L.marker(currentMarker).addTo(map).bindPopup(checkBounds(currentMarker)).openPopup()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's **L**ng not **lng**, you have a typo

L.lat**l**ngBounds vs L.lat**L**ngBounds

Comment: Guess those new progressive lenses I got aren't as good as I thought I they were. :)  TOTALLY missed that "L".  Thanks.  For those that care, the new code reads as such:

Comment: should have added the @alex, but did something funny as I was trying to back up.